# Strange merge messages when pushing to remote branch

Tags: git, github

We're working on a project with a few folks and have the following branch structure (on the server):

```
master
staging
contributions
```

I've asked people to work in the contributions branch and have asked them to clone their repository like this:

```
git clone repository_address -b contributions
```

I'm under the impression that the above command will clone the repository and switch into the contributions branch. I'm assuming the above command also is creating a local tracking branch that points to the remote `contributions` branch.

Here's the strange part: When someone pushes to the repository, the history on GitHub is as expected (you'll just see a list of commits). But if before one person pushes after another person has pushed, you see two commit messages for the later push in the form of:

[image]

This seems very counter intuitive to me because the message says "merging branch contributions into contributions". Also the log of such a commit just simply shows all the files that have been added to the branch since the last pull by that person.

What happened above is that P did a pull before a push, and then myself, I had to do a pull because of his changes before doing a push and both of us got an extra commit that says "merge".

Is there something wrong with our setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a `git pull`, you execute two commands: `git fetch` and `git merge`. Because of `git merge`, these merge commits will show in your log. To avoid this, you can use `git rebase` instead of `git merge`. For this, the easiest solution is to use `git pull --rebase`.